# jQuery performance is too slow (toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, toggle, performance-testing

I have the problem that the toggle function of jQuery is too low for my case. I need to toggle over 2000 rows and the script needs over 30 seconds.

How can I improve the performance ? Maybe only Javascript instead of jQuery?

```js
$('#toggleAspMaterials').click(function() {
    $('#catalog body.asp').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<input id="toggleAspMaterials" value="Show Asp Materials / hide" class="button" type="button">
```

Comment: Honestly, in this case you are probably better off just having a second table hidden on the page that reflects these changes that you want to make, and, instead of toggling all the rows, just toggle the display of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comparision between vanilla and jQuery, it's based on operations / second. So, yes, maybe just using JavaScript can optimize your case good enough.

[image]

[Diagram original source](http://blog.appsignal.com/blog/2013/02/15/jquery-toggle-is-slow-javascript-to-the-rescue.html)

Answer (score 0):

Cache the list of matching elements outside of the click function.

This will be faster because the time it takes JQ to hunt down all the elements will required once and after that there will be no per-click overhead for hunting.